# Separating columns in a dataframe by date format [np.datetime64] {there are 25 columns with different format in each column}

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have 25 date columns in a pandas dataframe, some have date and hour, others have only date. I want to change the format of the date columns with hour to a particular format and one only with dates to a particular format. Can someone help me with it?

I have firstly taken a subset of all the dateformat columns:

```
date_cols=week_y.select_dtypes(include=[np.datetime64])
```

I now want to separate the ones with hour+date from the ones with only date
And then change the format of hour+date columns to a particular format('mm/dd/yy hh:mm') and only date columns(mm/dd/yy) to another

[first few rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzi2D.png)

Comment: You should check `pandas.to_datetime`, you can use `format` parameter. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Yes but how do I separate the columns(ones with only date and the ones with date and hour) and then instead of manually changing each of them how do I iteratively change their formats

Comment: Post a few rows of your data frame

Comment: I have added the image